# Python Multiprocessing Process exits before operation

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have a python object - list of dictionaries which I want to fill with key-value pairs in each of those dicts but simultaneously using multiple processors and using the multiprocessing module in python. For that purpose I am using the Manager module for storing that python object. Here is the following code:

```
from pylab import *
from numpy.random import *
import multiprocessing
import threading
import random

def tasks_start(id, global_lists):
    counter_lock = threading.Lock()
    with counter_lock:
        num = int(10*random.random())
        global_lists[num] = {'1':'Random'}

    print("Id: ", id)
    print(global_lists[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    numProcessors = 6
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(numProcessors)

    global_list = multiprocessing.Manager().list(range(100))
    for idx in range(100):
        global_list[idx] = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()

    tasks = []
    for id in range(10):
        tasks.append((id, global_list))

    pool.starmap(tasks_start, tasks)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

So what I am doing here is creating a list of dictionaries stored as `global_list` and then calling the `tasks_start()` method 10 times using the python's `starmap()` module (just so that I can later extend to multiple arguments) to fill the list of dictionaries. As a simple test case, I just use the random generator to randomly pick up one dictionary among the lists everytime and fill it with some value. When I run the program, the following error occurs:

```
    multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "/home/cysis/inhibition_soum/motif_temporal_patterns/code_versions/2016/09/09_08/parallel_test/test_error_manager.py", line 14, in tasks_start
    print(global_lists[0])
  File "<string>", line 2, in __getitem__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 732, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 852, in RebuildProxy
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 706, in __init__
    self._incref()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 756, in _incref
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 495, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 624, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cysis/inhibition_soum/motif_temporal_patterns/code_versions/2016/09/09_08/parallel_test/test_error_manager.py", line 29, in <module>
    pool.starmap(tasks_start, tasks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 599, in get
    raise self._value
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

In my opinion before the last `print(global_lists[0)` is executed, the Manager exits and therefore is not able to find `global_lists[0]`. Can anybody shed some light on this sort of stuff?

Comment: did you get any solution